# Java - FIFO queuedatastructure

Tags: java, queue, fifo

I'm trying to make a FIFO queue with Java. But I don't know where to start.

I want to make two classes: one for Customer-information and one for Order-information.
The Customer-information contains things like:
- Customer ID
- Name
- Age

The Order contains information like:
- Customer ID
- Order ID
- Complete (yes/no)

And I want to implement an insert when their is a new order.
When a order is complete I want to delete the order.

Does anybody know how to start with this algorithm?
All tips are welcome.

Comment: You know, there is already Queue in java? LinkedList is one of it's implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to implement a queue by yourself or what?

If not, there is already a Queue interface in java.util.collections, with various implementations. You can use one of them - for example, LinkedList.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I will try LinkedList then.